# "Unknown JDBC type code .. at Column.setTypeCode" (DllUtils)

Tags: java, sql-server, apache

I am using DllUtils and wish to use it to generate the database schema into XML file. Does anyone know how to use it? I am using SQL Server for testing. Not sure how exactly I can get the DataSource object out of it. 
I am reading http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api-usage.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#datasource_connection I think there is something wrong with my "model" name, but I don't know what exactly it is supposed to be in order to get the Database object.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setDescription("Felix testing program");
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    ds.setPortNumber(1433);
    ds.setUser("test");
    ds.setPassword("1234");
    ds.setDatabaseName("database");

    try {
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
                "org.apache.naming"); 

        Hashtable<String, String> pdEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory"); 
        pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433");

        Context ctx = new InitialContext(pdEnv);
        ctx.bind("jdbc:sqlserver", ds);
        DataSource ds2 = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc:sqlserver");

        Database db = readDatabase(ds2);
        writeDatabaseToXML(db, "C:/Users/fcao/Documents/sample.xml");

        readDatabaseFromXML("C:/Users/fcao/Documents/sample.xml");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Database readDatabaseFromXML(String fileName)
{
    return new DatabaseIO().read(fileName);
}

public static void writeDatabaseToXML(Database db, String fileName)
{
    new DatabaseIO().write(db, fileName);
}

public static Database readDatabase(DataSource dataSource)
{
    Platform platform = PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(dataSource);

    return platform.readModelFromDatabase("model");
}

public static void changeDatabase(DataSource dataSource,
        Database   targetModel,
        boolean    alterDb)
{
    Platform platform = PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(dataSource);

    if (alterDb)
    {
        platform.alterTables(targetModel, false);
    }
    else
    {
        platform.createTables(targetModel, true, false);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ddlutils.model.ModelException:
>   Unknown JDBC type code -9     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.model.Column.setTypeCode(Column.java:215)     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.readColumn(JdbcModelReader.java:781)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.mssql.MSSqlModelReader.readColumn(MSSqlModelReader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.readColumns(JdbcModelReader.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.readTable(JdbcModelReader.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.mssql.MSSqlModelReader.readTable(MSSqlModelReader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.readTables(JdbcModelReader.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.getDatabase(JdbcModelReader.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.getDatabase(JdbcModelReader.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.PlatformImplBase.readModelFromDatabase(PlatformImplBase.java:1884)
>     at
>   org.apache.ddlutils.platform.PlatformImplBase.readModelFromDatabase(PlatformImplBase.java:1869)
>     at com.trillium.io.test.Main.readDatabase(Main.java:...)    at
>   com.trillium.io.test.Main.main(Main.java:...)

For the testing program, I have included jars: commons-betwixt-0.8 commons-collections-3.2.2 commons-lang-2.6 commons-logging-1.2 DdlUtils-1.0 sqljdbc4 jakarta-oro-2.0.1 naming-common-4.1.36 commons-digester3-3.2

I tried to change the readDatabase method:

```
public static Database readDatabase(DataSource dataSource)
{
    Platform platform = PlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(dataSource);

    Database db = null;
    try {
        db = platform.getModelReader().getDatabase(dataSource.getConnection(), "database");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return db;
}
```

From https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api/org/apache/ddlutils/Platform.html#readModelFromDatabase(java.sql.Connection, java.lang.String) documentation. What exactly is the name supposed to be if my database name is "database"...

> getDatabase
>
> public Database getDatabase(Connection connection,
>                               String name)
>                        throws SQLException Reads the database model from the given connection. Parameters: connection - The connection name -
>   The name of the resulting database; null when the default name (the
>   catalog) is desired which might be null itself though Returns: The
>   database model Throws: SQLException
>
> readModelFromDatabase
>
> Database readModelFromDatabase(Connection connection,
>                                  String name)
>                                  throws DatabaseOperationException Reads the database model from the live database to which the given
>   connection is pointing. Parameters: connection - The connection to the
>   database name - The name of the resulting database; null when the
>   default name (the catalog) is desired which might be null itself
>   though Returns: The database model Throws: DatabaseOperationException
>   - If an error occurred during reading the model

Comment: http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/databases/sqlserver.html

Comment: I tried to get my codes up to date and I have tried almost everything to understand how possible to get a DataSource object so I can get a Database object to use the writeDatabaseToXML method in DllUtils example to generate the xml file. If anyone can get the codes working, it will be awesome! ty

Comment: We have to really buildup few parts in ddlUtils framework..!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that ddlutils doesn't contain type mapping of nvarchar.

I took following way solved this issue:
First, use platform.readModelFromDatabase(name, databaseName, "dbo", new String[]{"TABLE"});
Then, rewrite org.apache.ddlutils.model.TypeMap as follow:
create class org.apache.ddlutils.model.TypeMap in project, copy all code into TypeMap, add following code into the static block,
registerJdbcType(-9, "VARCHAR", JdbcTypeCategoryEnum.TEXTUAL);
then it works.